# Not able to create a object with attributes

Tags: python

This is my code

class Dog():

```
def _init_(self,breed):
    
    self.breed = breed
```

And when I run

`my_dog = Dog(breed = "Lab")`

I get the following error

```
Dog() takes no arguments
```

If I run `my_dog = Dog()`

then there is no error!!

Comment: `_init_` --> `__init__`

Comment: Two underscores (dunderscore)`__init__` please refer more......

Answer (score 1):

You define a constructor the wrong way

```
def __init__ (self, breed, name):
    self.breed = breed
```